# Multimap<Hoge, Fuga> の初期化方法を教えてください

Tags: java, guava

`Multimap<Hoge, Fuga>` を必要とするメソッドがあるのですが、Multimaps.index を使うよりも簡単な初期化方法はありませんか？

```
Multimap<Hoge, Fuga> piyo = Multimaps.初期化();
```

くらい簡単なものがうれしいです。環境はJava6です。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

空のMapが欲しいという事でしたら `ArrayListMultimap.create()`でどうでしょうか。
もしくはMultimapBuilderというモノもあります。